# Serializing a sqlalchemy hybrid_property using marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using sqlalchemy and marshmallow in my RESTful flask application to serialize my models. I have a hybrid_property that comes from one of my relationships on that model. I would like to now serialize that hybrid_property in my schema using the schema from the related model.

Has anyone done this before? Here are my relevant pieces of code. It doesn't seem to be including the `last_assessment` in the serialized version of the model when I check the response

```
class Person(db.Model):
  daily_rula_average_ranges = db.relationship('DailyRulaAverageRange', order_by="DailyRulaAverageRange.date", back_populates='person')

  @hybrid_property
  def last_assessment(self):
    if self.daily_rula_average_ranges.length > 0:
      return self.daily_rula_average_ranges[-1]

class PersonSchema(ma.Schema):
  last_assessment = ma.Nested(DailyRulaAverageRangeSchema, only=['id', 'date', 'risk'])
  class Meta:
    fields = ('last_assessment')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried stacking the `@property` decorator on top of the hybrid_property one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit sneaky, but I believe the problem is that the line `if self.daily_rula_average_ranges.length > 0:` is causing an AttributeError to be raised, because length is not usually an attribute of lists.  You probably meant `if len(self.daily_rula_average_ranges) > 0:` .

Here's an ORM-agnostic example - the serializer returns no field if an attribute error is raised, but returns data fine if appropriate data is returned by the property:

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema
from marshmallow.fields import Nested

class DailyRulaAverageRangeSchema(Schema):
    id=fields.UUID()
    date=fields.Date()
    risk=fields.Integer()

class PersonSchema(Schema):
    last_assessment = Nested(DailyRulaAverageRangeSchema, only=['id', 'date', 'risk'])
    class Meta:
        fields = ('last_assessment',)

class Person(object):
    @property
    def last_assessment(self):
        raise AttributeError('oops')

PersonSchema().dump(Person())

# Out[73]: {}

class Person(object):
    @property
    def last_assessment(self):
        return {"id": None, "date":None, 'risk': 100}   

PersonSchema().dump(Person())
# Out[83]: {u'last_assessment': {u'date': None, u'id': None, u'risk': 100}}
```

It is not too surprising that marshmallow behaves this way because an attribute that raises an AttributeError will appear as though the attribute does not exist, e.g.:

```
class Person(object):
    @property
    def last_assessment(self):
        raise AttributeError('oops')

hasattr(Person(), 'last_assessment')
# Out: False
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try and take a look at this fix ASAP so I can reward you the bounty if it's correct. Have to wait till I get home from work though sadly

Comment: Yep looks like that was the fix, thank you very much. I blame working with rails